# is it possible to use one regex to extract from 2 data format

Tags: .net, regex

for the two different format of data to extract account Desc, number, and balance, ignoring account type and available balance for now

```
---------------------- 160215 ( no Available balance)::::::::::::::::

                 U$ GG Hi interest2 - Savings 09999-9999385
Savings 09999-9999385 USD $9.00
-- or
U$ GG Hi interest2 - Savings 09999-9999385
Savings 09999-9999385 USD $9.00
---------------------- 160207 (has avail Balance):::::

                 U$ GG Hi interest3  Savings 09999-4500399 Available Balance: $5000.00 USD
$4500.00 USD

------- or:
U$ GG Hi interest3  Savings 09999-4500399 Available Balance: $5000.00 USD  $4500.00 USD
```

In summary, the difference of the 2 data format is

- 2nd fmt has available balance after desc., acct type, acct # on the same first logical line
- 1st fmt has only acct type, acct # after description in the first logical line but with acct type, acct # repeated on the 2nd line before the acct balance curency and actual balance in the 2nd logical line

I tried many regex but only the one below describes the possible format. I tried using or but was not able to come with proper regex

the following got the first type of format:

```
@"(
)(\t| ){8,18}(?<desc>
    U[$]
    (\s
        [a-z',._()]{0,30}
        (
            [a-z]
            [0-9]{0,2}
        ){0,1}
    ){1,10}
)\s([-]\s((Chequing)|(Savings)|(\w\w\w+))\s+(\d+[-]\d+)\s+){0,1}[
]((Chequing)|(Savings)|(\w\w\w+))\s+(?<acctNumb>\d+[-]\d+)\s+\w\w\w\s+\$
(?<bal>
    \d{1,3}
    (,\d\d\d){0,4}
    \.
    \d{1,2}
)\b
"
```

with Regex Options IgnoreCase, ExplicitCapture, Multi-line, IgnorePatternWhitespace

Comment: You should clean up your formatting, and show us what you want to extract.  The answer to your question is yes, you can extract 2 things from a single regex using capture groups.

Comment: What exactly is the text from your example which makes up a description? Be specific on what should be captured, you have provided rules, but the rules are **too vague** against what you show as data.

Comment: thank you for replying.

the description must start with the two letters u$ or somehow make sure  the 3 letter word before balance is usd. the description must have at least one word starting with an alphabet excluding u$. Not restriction on any subsequent word in the logical line. the description is set up by user with hardly any restriction on one or more 3rd party website.
 
 what is desired to capture is the description, acct number, and the balance regardless of position in the data

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: Please illustrate the expected output. I have no idea where an acct#, balance, etc. are. E.g. for the first entry, the result should be *Account number*: `160215`, balance: `9.00`, etc.

Comment: Try `(?<desc>\bU\$.*?)(?:\s*-+\s*)?Savings\s*(?<acnt>\d+-\d+).*?(?:USD|Balance)\W*(?<bal>[\d.]+)`

Comment: ...oops click by mistake the delete button. 
<p> An array of corresponding rows of desc, acct#, balance for now. 
<B>U$ GG Hi interest2 09999-9999385 $9.00

<p>However, I'm more interested in getting a regex that will match both formats of data. I can do the rest of extraction.

<p>I suspect it may not be possible to use one single regex for tow different format with target located in different position; at least from my limited regex skill perspective.

<p>if not possible for a single regex, please let me know. I will then iterate through a couple of regex for extract

Comment: thank you, Wiktor. the regex seems fine but the moment the last group is included, @"(?‌​<bal>[\d.,]+)", the regex fails to compile with  
    Unrecognized grouping construct  
using alternate construct *(?‌​<bal>[,.0-9]+) did not help.  
what is the purpose of "?" before before the left Parenthesis?  
    ?(?:USD|Balance)  
Btw I tried  
    (?<desc>\bU\$.*?)(?:\s*-+\s*)?Savings\s*(?<acnt>\d+-\d+)\s.*?(?<a>(USD|Balance))\W*[$](?<bal>[0-9,.]+)  
no Syntax; extracted only the desc from the 2 lines in the 2nd format only; not the first type  
I guess have to use 2 regex to get them all.

Comment: when you address someone in a comment, please add a `@` before the name, or the user won't get notified. Please add all updates to the question with proper formatting. My regex works well for the data you provided (see goo.gl/XBsyml) (select the `goo.gl/XBsyml` and right-click and go the shortened URL of the regex demo). If you plan to use the regex in C#, use `@"(?isx)(?<desc>\bU\$.*?)(?:\s*-+\s*)?Savings\s*(?<acnt>\d+-\d+).*?(?:USD|Balance)\W*(?<bal>[\d.]+)"` - there cannot be any errors if you copy/paste the pattern correctly.

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I used the http://regexstorm.net/tester with copy and paste with ignorecase, explicit capture<br/>  
  and got only the data with available balance but not the ones without.<br/>
 ref image: [link extract result https://docs.google.com/drawings   /d/1ZJRPprTAOiwkYNiFwFMAFJrwZhCpFU1ObwAFnMQIhek/edit?usp=sharing]  
<br/>

Comment: On your screenshot, the `Singleline` option is not selected, while I clearly marked it in my demo, and also used it as an inline option in the comment above ("(?i**s**x)").

Comment: thank you. I made of mistake of specifying the IC and Explicit while using ("(?isx)") in the regex. hence it did not work and then after taking it out, I missed the SingleLine

Comment: So, is that working or not? Shall I post the `goo.gl/XBsyml` solution for you to accept?

Comment: @wiktor, thank you. it works well for the present requirement now, although I can foresee  having trouble for extracting available balance down the road.
 
go head to post the goo.gl/XBsyml solution for me to accept?

Comment: Posted an answer. Please next time be a bit more precise with the requirements, so that relevant help could come faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<desc>\bU\$.*?)(?:\s*-+\s*)?Savings\s*(?<acnt>\d+-\d+).*?(?:USD|Balance)\W*(?<bal>[\d.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cdesc%3E%5CbU%5C%24.*%3F)(%3F%3A%5Cs*-%2B%5Cs*)%3FSavings%5Cs*(%3F%3Cacnt%3E%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B).*%3F(%3F%3AUSD%7CBalance)%5CW*(%3F%3Cbal%3E%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B)&i=----------------------%20160215%20(%20no%20Available%20balance)%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20U%24%20GG%20Hi%20interest2%20-%20Savings%2009999-9999385%0D%0ASavings%2009999-9999385%20USD%20%249.00%0D%0A--%20or%0D%0AU%24%20GG%20Hi%20interest2%20-%20Savings%2009999-9999385%0D%0ASavings%2009999-9999385%20USD%20%249.00%0D%0A----------------------%20160207%20(has%20avail%20Balance)%3A%3A%3A%3A%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20U%24%20GG%20Hi%20interest3%20%20Savings%2009999-4500399%20Available%20Balance%3A%20%245000.00%20USD%0D%0A%244500.00%20USD%0D%0A%0D%0A-------%20or%3A%0D%0AU%24%20GG%20Hi%20interest3%20%20Savings%2009999-4500399%20Available%20Balance%3A%20%3E%20%245000.00%20USD%20%20%244500.00%20USD&o=ixcs)

Use it with ignorecase and singleline modifiers.

**Details**:

- `(?<desc>\bU\$.*?)` - Group "desc" capturing a `U` after a word boundary, a `$` and then any 0+ chars (with `.*?`), as few as possible up to the first...
- `(?:\s*-+\s*)?` - optional sequence of 0+ whitespaces, 1+ `-`s and 0+ whitespaces (this group might be redundant since it will only match if it follows `U$` immediately)
- `Savings\s*` - `Savings` with 0+ whitespaces after it
- `(?<acnt>\d+-\d+)` - Group "acnt" capturing 1+ digits, a `-` and 1+ digits
- `.*?` - zero or more any chars as few as possible up to the first
- `(?:USD|Balance)` - either `USD` or `Balance` text
- `\W*` - 0+ chars that are not word chars (other than letters, digits and an underscore)
- `(?<bal>[\d.]+)` - Group "bal" capturing 1+ digits or dots.

Note that `.*?` does not always let you grab the smallest window between 2 subpatterns, as backtracking will try to accommodate for all obligatory capturing groups in the pattern. In case your input is structured, you should think of using more restricting patterns based on negated character classes and shorthands like `\w`, `\d`, `\S`.